# Moving Facebook application to another account

Tags: .net, facebook, flash

We have created 3 facebook applications under one account. Now we would like to move once of the application to another facebook account. Please help us how to move the app?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook deployment and not development

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps:

1. Add the new Account to the App's Administrators List in Facebook Developer App Console ( `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{YOUR_APP_ID}/roles?ref=nav` )
2. After the new Account accepted the Admin role, remove the old account from Administrator role
3. Done